# Find test that provided code coverage to a portion of code in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2019

I am making changes to an existing code base and ran Visual Studio Code Coverage tool to obtain code coverage against all tests in the test project. I see that areas that have code coverage are highlighted. However, is there an easy way to find which test provided coverage for a portion of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio CodeLens provides a feature called [Associated Unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019#associated-unit-tests) which shows all unit tests associated with the method. This was what I was looking for.